# Change spinner states dynamically

Tags: android, spinner, state

I am trying to change state style of a spinner programmatically.

But when I press an item, all of them are changed!
Before pressing everything's fine, the colors are good:

[image]

When pressing, all items become green:
[image]

I did this in my custom adapter :

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //getting the views and all the stuff

    StateListDrawable colorStateList = new StateListDrawable();
    colorStateList.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
    colorStateList.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused                              }, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
    colorStateList.addState(new int[] {                              android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
    colorStateList.addState(new int[] {                                                          }, new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));

    holder.container.setBackgroundDrawable(colorStateList);

    return convertView;
}
```

Here is my custom dropdown layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinner_container"
android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_ligne_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_ligne_size"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_dir1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_arrow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_dir2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(I know this is uggly but this is just for testing)

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you want the color to be green when being pressed? From your code `colorStateList.addState(new int[] {                              android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));` it looks like that's what you want it to do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want BUT only the item pressed, not ALL of them. I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in

> getDropDownView

```
        mTextViewBackgroundListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        mTextViewBackgroundListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
        mTextViewBackgroundListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
        mTextViewBackgroundListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, new ColorDrawable(0));

        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(mTextViewBackgroundListDrawable);
```

Declare "mTextViewBackgroundListDrawable" variable globally in your custom adapter.

It solve my problem. Hope this help.

Comment: Nice. This could allow to convert a `ColorStateList` into a `StateListDrawable`, which you sometimes need to change a TextView background color on state change.